# Cannot bind argument to parameter '' because it is null

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1, powershell-7.3

I have this strange observation and I don't know how to cope with this:

I'm reading a list of files from a directory. I pipe these through a sequence of `Select-Object`, `Sort-Object`, `Select-Object` calls in order to retrieve just a single property. Finally, I feed the result to a pipe.

Now, when `Get-ChildItem` retrieves no files, I get the error message: `Cannot bind argument to parameter 'File' because it is null.`

#### Here's an MRE:

```
function Test
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]$File
  )
  process { }
}


$arr = (Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.xxxx' |
    Select-Object -Property 'Name',
    @{
      name = 'FileObject'
      expression = { $_ }
    } |
    Sort-Object -Property 'Name').FileObject


$arr | Test
```

(Please note: this is just an MRE, not a meaningful piece of code. Don't focus on the `Select-Object` expression.)

When I change the last line to: `Sort-Object -Property 'Name')` by removing the `.FileObject`, everything runs flawlessly.

An empty array is an empty array, I guess. In both cases, `$arr -eq $null` is `$true`. So, why do I get different behaviour? How can I make this run flawlessly (and still being strict) with the `FileObject` property still being the return type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between `$null` and `AutomationNull.Value`. When Cmdlets, Functions and Script Blocks return nothing what you actually get is this type of null value but then by expanding on the `.FileObject` property when the statement returned `Automation.Value` you're effectively getting `$null` instead.

> If you try to access a property or sub property of an object that doesn't have the specified property, you get a `$null` value like you would for an undefined variable. It doesn't matter if the variable is `$null` or an actual object in this case.

See [**Everything you wanted to know about `$null`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null?view=powershell-7.3) for more details.

```bash
$var1 = $null
$var2 = & { }

function Test {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]$File
    )
    begin { 'begin' }
    process { 'process' }
    end { 'end' }
}

$var1 | Test # fails on `process` block
$var2 | Test # only `begin` and `end` are called, no items are bound from pipeline
$var2.SomProperty | Test # now is `$null`, thus same issue as first example
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your very informative and thorough explanation, including the link to the full documentation! 

Comment: @AxD glad this was helpful happy to help